# Cypress extension load into test runner iFrame

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, cypress

I am trying to test a chrome extension with cypress and can successfully load the extension into cypress using the `before:browser:launch` event.

This will successfully install the extension to the browser, but the extension does not run in the same context as the test runner iFrame and therefore cannot get information from the page within the test runner.

I have also tried to install an older plugin called `cypress-browser-extension-plugin` to load the extension into cypress which does not seem to be working. Has anyone been successful loading an extension into the actual test runner of cypress without having to heavily modify the extension to be injected into the test runner?

I'm not sure how loading the extension into cypress the default way where it's installed on the browser but not running in the test runner iFrame is helpful for writing tests against the extension, ideally the extension would be running inside the test runner and able to interact with the page that cypress is currently testing right?

Answer (score 2):

While running in to the same problem I found this answer in another  thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72876307

Just add `"all_frames": true` to your extensions `manifest.json` under the `"content_scripts"` section.

Link to the docs: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#frames

I created a minimal reproduction repo for the solution as well: https://github.com/leonbubova/cypress-chrome-extension-minimal-reproduction