# Cypress - Chrome Extension not working inside Cypress Test Runner iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, cypress

I have a chrome extension that I successfully loaded into my Cypress environment. It shows up successfully in my extensions and I can see that it is turned on. I know it is working because I can open a new tab in the same browser where Cypress is running and it is working fine and making changes to the UI.

The problem is, the main tab that is running the Cypress Test Runner is inside of an iFrame and I suspect that the chrome extension I have loaded cannot interact with it. [I believe this issue reflects my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73046057/cypress-extension-load-into-test-runner-iframe). However, I tried that solution but with no luck.

[There is a blog that I stumbled upon](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/01/07/how-to-load-the-react-devtools-extension-in-cypress/) that talks about a solution for fixing this for the *React Dev Tools Extension*. The following screenshot explains:

[image]

However, the extension that I am using does not have some kind of Global Hook like `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__` that I can take advantage of as far as I can tell.

I have no idea what to try next, if anyone can provide some guidance I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using *Puppeteer* for testing this particular extension. *Puppeteer* does not run within an iFrame allowing the extension to be testable, also you can integrate it into Cypress. Its an annoying workaround but I'm not seeing a better way to do it.